# Java - Not able to print all the Output in a text file and getting array out of bound exception

Tags: java

```
package Test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TestCode {

  public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
    //Getting files from the folder     

    File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\testing\\");

    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
      HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
      String line;
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.length() > 0) {
          String[] parts = line.split(",", 28);
          //System.out.println("LENGTH:" +parts.length);

          if (parts.length >=0) {
            //Concatenating FirstName and LastName

            String key = parts[2] + "_" + parts[4];
            map.put(key, line);
            String a= args[0];
            if (key.equals(a)) {

              System.out.println(key + ":" + map.get(key)); 

              String b = key + "," + map.get(key);

              String text = b;
              BufferedWriter output = null;

              // Trying to print all the outputs to a different file

              try {
                File file1 = new File("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\Output\\output.txt");
                output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1));
                output.write(text);
              } catch ( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              } finally {
                if ( output != null ) {
                  output.close();
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      reader.close();
    }
  }
}
```

My requirement is to read files from a folder and search for a particular user (Firstname_LastName) in all the files and print the Output to .txt file.

In the above code am getting array out of bound exception in line `String key = parts[2] + "_" + parts[4];` when i use a file containing very large number of users and it works fine for less number of users and also am missing something because only one file output is stored at the output file. Please help me out with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: Code formatting

Comment: Yes, I am getting the below error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at com.jarexport.FileTest.main(FileTest.java:30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String key = parts[2] + "_" + parts[4];
```

This means, you are expecting the `parts` array length will be always at least 5. Make sure the length is not less than 5.

```
if (parts.length >= 5) {
    String key = parts[2] + "_" + parts[4];
    ...
```

Comment: Hi @Shahid. thank you for your reply. I have some blank lines in the input file. How to change the code based on that.

Comment: Why have you added `if(line.length() > 0)` in your code?

Comment: I forgot to removethe if loop, while posting the question. Thank you for that. I have fixed it now. I want to write all the output to the Output.csv file. It would be very much greatful if you can see what i am missing in the try catch block

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly? Handling blank lines in the input file or writing in the output file?

Comment: Problem is writing to the output file. Let me briefly explain,  The folder in which i search contains multiple log files of the users. When i search for the particular user it must pull his entries from all the log files present and the same needed to be copied to an Output file for future reference. As of now i am able to see the output in the console but the Output file contains only a single entry. I think the Output is overwritten in the same file.

Comment: Your try catch block for creating and writing file is in the loops. That means every time loop iterates a new file replacing the previous file. Creating your output file outside the loop would solve your problem I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Check the parts array size greater than or not.

> String[] parts = line.split(",", 28);

Because if one line does't have 4 comma separated values it will break the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, actually i am having some blank lines in the input csv file